# Не могу авторизоваться через SSH

Tags: github, ssh, gitlab

Я установил Kubuntu 20.04 сегодня и пытаюсь настроить мой гитхаб и гитлаб для использования с SSH.
Одна ключ-пара была сгенерирована (~/.ssh/env), и конфиг ~/.ssh/config установлен следующим образом:

```
Host glab
 HostName gitlab.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/env
 IdentitiesOnly yess
```

Локальный репозиторий настроен таким образом:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@glab:REPOSNAME/service-logger.git
```

REPOSNAME = название моего репозитория.

Права доступа для директорий:
ls -loga ~/.ssh

```sh
drwx------  2 4096 дек 12 18:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 4096 дек 12 16:45 ..
-rwx------  1  153 дек 12 18:00 config
-rwx------  1  411 дек 12 15:26 env
-rwx------  1  102 дек 12 15:26 env.pub
```

Где "." текущая директория, и ".." это "/home/МОЯ ДОМ. ПАПКА/" dir.

Ssh-add -l показывает:

```sh
256 SHA256:mLphKZQdLR+iVKx5/jUa5NsCVo3swmuo79Yv6sw9mMs israfil22@whiteflame (ED25519)
```

`/var/log/auth.log | grep -a "ssh"` = пустой вывод.

Логи ssh -vvT git@glab:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/israfil22/.ssh/env ED25519 SHA256:mLphKZQdLR+iVKx5/jUa5NsCVo3swmuo79Yv6sw9mMs explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/israfil22/.ssh/env ED25519 SHA256:mLphKZQdLR+iVKx5/jUa5NsCVo3swmuo79Yv6sw9mMs explicit agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Логи при вводе комманды "ssh -vv" ТАКИЕ ЖЕ:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/israfil22/.ssh/env ED25519 SHA256:mLphKZQdLR+iVKx5/jUa5NsCVo3swmuo79Yv6sw9mMs explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/israfil22/.ssh/env ED25519 SHA256:mLphKZQdLR+iVKx5/jUa5NsCVo3swmuo79Yv6sw9mMs explicit agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: вы в настройках пользователя гитлаба точно добавили публичный ключ?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov напишите в ответ. Закину + за старания. Оказывается, залил не тот ключ на оба из хостов. Надо же было придумать себе проблему на  несколько часов....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по логу, не подходит ключ.

Проверьте публичный ключ в настройках пользователя гитлаба.